# Writing simple spreadsheet processor for class. The Location class' methods don't pass unit testing. Any help on why?

Tags: java, string, unit-testing, integer, spreadsheet

Writing up a program for a class and I have the specification to do this: A class that fully implements the Location interface, and contains a constructor taking a single String parameter (e.g., “D20”). My class is

```
package textExcel;

//Update this file with your own code.

public class SpreadsheetLocation implements Location
{
String Loc;
private int col = Integer.parseInt(Loc.substring(1, 2));
private int row = Integer.parseInt(Loc.substring(0, 0));
@Override
public int getRow()
{
    System.out.println(row);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return row;
}

@Override
public int getCol()
{
    System.out.println(col);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return col;
}

public SpreadsheetLocation(String cellName)
{
    Loc = cellName;

}

}
```

the interface is

```
 public interface Location
 {
// represents a location like B6, must be implemented by your SpreadsheetLocation class
int getRow(); // gets row of this location
int getCol(); // gets column of this location
 }
```

and the unit test is

```
public void testLongShortStringCell()
    {
        SpreadsheetLocation loc = new SpreadsheetLocation("L20");
        assertEquals("SpreadsheetLocation column", 11, loc.getCol());
        assertEquals("SpreadsheetLocation row", 19, loc.getRow());

        loc = new SpreadsheetLocation("D5");
        assertEquals("SpreadsheetLocation column", 3, loc.getCol());
        assertEquals("SpreadsheetLocation row", 4, loc.getRow());

        loc = new SpreadsheetLocation("A1");
        assertEquals("SpreadsheetLocation column", 0, loc.getCol());
        assertEquals("SpreadsheetLocation row", 0, loc.getRow());
    }
```

What might be causing my code to fail the unit test?

Comment: what do your assertions give as result? they should log the reason why

Comment: Did you try [running it](https://ideone.com/fkErD5)?

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to parse `Loc` before initializing it, resulting in a `NullPointerException`.

After moving the parsing to the constructor, you'll still need to fix it tough. The column is denoted by a letter, and you can't just parse it as an `int` - you'd need to get the difference between it and `A`, under the simplifying assumption that it can only have a single character:

```
public SpreadsheetLocation(String cellName) {
    loc = cellName;
    row = Integer.parseInt(loc.substring(1)) - 1;
    col = loc.charAt(0) - 'A';
}
```